# mysql query returns different results when calculating with stored value and actual number

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line, phpmyadmin, local

So I've done a lot of research and I cannot seem to find someone with the same problem.
I was using a query to find to closest destinations with this document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

It worked find when I was doing local tests. However, when I switched to AWS RDS, the calculation went very wrong.

It all comes down to this:
When I do a query with a stored value on my localhost mysql, it returns a different result from when I do a query with an actual value.

(Only one row in my table, and the longitude value is -177.744302.)

So when I did:

```
SELECT (longitude * pi() / 180) AS temp
FROM table1;
```

I would get `-2.0550257453625447`.

But when I use:

```
SELECT (-177.744302 * pi() / 180) AS temp 
FROM table1;
```

I would get `-3.1022232966`.

I have no idea why this is happening and I can't seem to figure out why. And this only happens when I'm doing it on localhost mysql. When I use it on AWS RDS the result for both queries are `-3.102223966`. And mathematically `-3.102223966` is the correct answer, but `-2.05502574` is the one I need to calculate the correct distance. So this is very ironic and confusing to me.

AWS RDS has mysql version 5.6.13 and localhost mysql is 5.6.14, but I don't think this is the reason why. But it just does not make sense at all. If anyone has been through similar problem please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in your table is -117.744302 and not -177.744302

Comment: I'm so sorry guys, this is such a stupid mistake. I guess I've just been looking at the numbers for over 5 hours, because I was trying to migrate from local to RDS. It was a typo in my data, and that's why there's different results from local and rds. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

-2.0550257453625447 * 180 / pi() = -117.744.. , not -177.744... , looks like a typo